# Refactoring ViewModel mapping - dealing with multiple service calls

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, mvvm, automapper

I need to refactor and tidy the following controller below, it's my first MVC application. I've successfully used AutoMapper as I began refactor controllers but I am not sure how to approach a scenario where the **data** for the ViewModel comes from **multiple service calls**. And that scenario seems to often present itself in slightly heavier view models where I have all kind of information to present.

Calling multiple mapping calls on top of the same view model seemed counter-intuitive and it feels like I am missing some good practice or common approach to the situation. Or maybe I am wrong and it's commonly used approach.

**0)** Thought of generally using AutoMapper somehow but as I said I cannot find a proper way to implement it, I'd like to keep the controller relatively thin but I also don't want to have too much unneeded/overkill abstraction. I know how to map the TaskEvent properties for example, even though I haven't.

**1)** Thought of having some build method on the view model and to pass needed data.

**2)** Thought of having a model between my database entities and the view model but I am not sure how to execute that either, I think I seen somewhere by examples that people return "Models" from service calls that contain complex data and then map those Models to the ViewModel with Automapper, instead of mapping service calls and domain entities directly into the ViewModel like others are doing.

**3)** Saw people use a ***facade*** of sorts in one example and thought of that too.

It's just my first project under MVC and I would like to ***learn a robust general approach that is considered well written and good practice*** so I can use it to fully refactor this and continue to improve from there.

```
        BKQEventCustomData BKQEventData = BKQHelper.ParseBase64EventData(Server.UrlDecode(Request.Url.Query));
        var cutomData = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<NopOrderData>(BKQEventData.custom.data.ToString());

        var model = new TaskEventViewModel();
        if (BKQEventData != null)
        {
            AuthenticateRequest(BKQEventData.xcm.clid, BKQEventData.xcm.opid);

            model.PlacesList = new SelectList(_placesService.GetPlacesByClientId(BKQProfile.ClientId).Where(p => p.Active), "PlaceId", "Name");
            model.ServicesList = new SelectList(_serviceService.GetServicesByClientId(BKQProfile.ClientId).Where(s => s.Active), "ServiceId", "Name");
            model.ContractorsList = new SelectList(_contractorService.GetContractorsByClientId(BKQProfile.ClientId), "ContractorId", "BKQFullName");
            model.StatusList = new SelectList(_statusService.GetStatusByClientId(BKQProfile.ClientId), "StatusId", "Name");

            model.TaskEvent = new TaskEvent();
            model.TaskEvent.Title = string.Empty;
            model.TaskEvent.BKQCustomData = BKQEventData.custom.data.ToString();
            model.TaskEvent.BKQCustomDataType = BKQEventData.custom.type.ToString();
            model.TaskEvent.BKQClientId = BKQEventData.xcm.clid;
            model.TaskEvent.BKQOperatorId = BKQEventData.xcm.opid;
            model.TaskEvent.BKQInfProductId = BKQEventData.xcm.iprodid;
            model.TaskEvent.BKQEventHistoryId = BKQEventData.xcm.evnhid;
            model.TaskEvent.BKQEventTypeId = BKQEventData.xcm.evntype;
            model.TaskEvent.BKQEventCaseId = BKQEventData.xcm.caseid;
            model.TaskEvent.BKQQuota = BKQEventData.xcm.quotaid;
            model.TaskEvent.BKQLangId = BKQEventData.xcm.langid;
            model.TaskEvent.BKQContactId = BKQEventData.xcm.contid;
            model.TaskEvent.CreatedBy = BKQEventData.xcm.opid;
            model.TaskEvent.ModifiedBy = BKQEventData.xcm.opid;
            model.BKQContact = BKQFramework.Contact.GetById(BKQEventData.xcm.contid);
        }
        else
        {
            return RedirectToActionPermanent("Login", "Login");
        }
```

Comment: Just for clarification, you want to just tidy up this bit of code?  I think I'm a little confused as to what you're questions are.

Comment: I want to tidy and refactor it in a proper and robust way, but I am not sure how to approach it, perhaps SO isn't the place for this. I posted on code review as well. I've seen loads of approaches and I am confused which one is the most common.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how I would refactor it

1. The controller should not reference too many serivces, I would put
   all the service dependencies into an ApplicationService
2. The code that creates the ViewModel should set together with code that 
   defines the ViewModel. This makes it convenient to modify ViewModel definition and property assignment at the same time. I would you a static function to create the ViewModel.
3. I would think twice about using AutoMapper. If most properties can not be mapped automatically, AutoMapper won't give you any benefit. The static function approach gives you static type checking and also a much better debug experience than AutoMapper.

   ```
   BKQEventCustomData BKQEventData = BKQHelper.ParseBase64EventData(Server.UrlDecode(Request.Url.Query));
   var cutomData = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<NopOrderData>(BKQEventData.custom.data.ToString());

   if (BKQEventData != null)
   {
       AuthenticateRequest(BKQEventData.xcm.clid, BKQEventData.xcm.opid);
       var model = _applicationService.CreateMyViewModel(BKQeventData);
   }
   else
   {
       return RedirectToActionPermanent("Login", "Login");
   }

   pubilc class MyApplicationService : IMyApplicationService
   {
       public CreateTaskEventViewModel(BKQeventCustomData)
       {
           var model = new TaskEventViewModel();
           var services =  _placesService.GetPlacesByClientId(BKQProfile.ClientId).Where(p => p.Active);
           var contractors = _contractorService.GetContractorsByClientId(BKQProfile.ClientId);
           var statuses = _statusService.GetStatusByClientId(BKQProfile.ClientId);

           return TaskEventViewModel.CreateFromBKQCustomData(model, serivces, contractors, statuses);
       }   
   }

   public class TaskEventViewModel
   {
       public static CreateFromBKQCustomData(BKQCustomData bKQCustomData, IEnumerable<Serivce> services, ...)
       {
            var model = new TaskEventViewModel();
            model.PlacesList = new SelectList(services, "PlaceId", "Name");
            ...

            model.TaskEvent = TaskEvent.CreateFromBKQEventData(model);
            model.BKQContact = BKQFramework.Contact.GetById(BKQEventData.xcm.contid);
       }
   }
   ```

Comment: You given me some great ideas, although I disagree on the fact that the controller shouldn't refer too many services. But I will look into that as well.